# Declare custom xml attributes namespace globally

Tags: android

Is it possible to add custom attributes namespace to every xml/layout files in android project rather than having to declare this at the header of every single file?

```
xmlns:namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: AFAIK, no. Not from Android/Google officially.

Comment: @AndrewT. do you have source of that information? If you do, can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as a selected answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have source for that. That was only from my observation on tutorials/guides on Android Developers that I have read (the [`support-v7` Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) and [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)), and maybe some other Android tutorials blog; I haven't seen anything like what you want. That's why I'm still hesitating to put it as an answer.